# getting 500 internet server error on godaddy while using php email

Tags: php, mysql, sql, email

i want to send email to my 600 clients through php email. but the loop works till 20 contacts, after that it show 500 internal server error... 
i am using go daddy server.

```
<?php
for($x=1;$x<=600;$x++)
{
$con = mysqli_connect("host","database","password");
if (!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));}
mysqli_select_db($con,"database");
$sql="SELECT email FROM emails Where id = ".$x;
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$to = $row['email'];
if ($to == "NULL")
{

}
else
{
  echo $row['email'];
mysqli_close($con);
// mail($to,"subject","message");
sleep(2);
}
}
?>
```

Comment: im sure godaddy will limit the number of emails you can send in X minutes

Comment: go daddy limits the amount of emails a single script can send at one time on certain hosting levels.

Comment: in addition doing 600 queries is crazy, get them all and loop

Comment: As Dagon hinted to, never loop queries. Fetch them all at once.

Comment: Whay dont u try http://serverfault.com/ this to ask this type of question?

Comment: @Dagon, thank you very much, i have tried your idea, but still i am getting this godaddy 500 error !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to send unlimited mails in a short period time is restricted by most of the hosting servers. If u continuously try to do this, they may even block ur hosting account temporarily or permanent.
But if u want to send unlimited mails there are lot of third party mail services available. U can use those to send unlimited mails.